# changes in products are not getting saved in magento 1.9 even after cleared cache and Indexed as well

Tags: magento-1.9

I am not able to make any changes in the product page in my website in magento1.90 and after clicking the save button it is just loading and nothing else

Comment: can you please check and share the logs created during the button trigger?